# PHPStorm: auto sync creation/editing/deletion of files and folders automatically?

Tags: synchronization, sftp, phpstorm

I've just got PHPStorm for a 30 days trial and I like it, but coming from Notepad++ I need the SFTP sync. I set up the connection to my remote server (DigitalOcean) and I can browse the server, open a ssh connection in the console and sync manually the local files with the server files.

The problem is that it won't auto sync when for example I save a file on local.

In `Settings\deployment\options` I set `Upload changed files automatically..` to `On explicit save Action (CTRL + S)` and restarted the IDE.

But when I save a file locally it won't sync with the one on the server.

I have to manually right-click the local file and select `Sync with deployed to..`, at which point the window with the difference between the two files is shown. Here I have to manually sync them.

This process is very slow so I want the file to automatically upload to the server.

Also, if possible, when I create a file or folder on local, the file or folder to be also created on the server.

All the permissions are set to `777` on the server also.

Is there some kind of bug ?

[This](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Sync+changes+and+automatic+upload+to+a+deployment+server+in+PhpStorm) is the guide I followed.

Comment: Have you marked your deployment server as Default for this project? Sounds like not. Auto upload only works with Default entry.

Comment: @LazyOne I am not really sure, but in the SFTP configuration for the server, I set the mapping folder to the one on my local computer. Is this the Default option ? If not, where can I set this ?  Ok, I managed to set it as Default and now it syncs automatically, thank you so much.  Just a quick question, what are the preferable permissions on the server directory to allow auto upload ? Right now I have set them to 777

Comment: Why don't you leave them as is? Default permission may be the best for most of your files (those that you do not plan to modify by your own code -- e.g. temp/cache files/logs etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have not marked your deployment server as Default for this project. Automatic upload works with Default entry ONLY.

You can do this at `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Deployment`.